# Use Measure-Command to know http request time, but how do you get an average, minimum and maximum?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that queries something in Sharpeoint, then with each document id, it executes a webservice, I am familiar with the measure-command cmdlet and works pretty fine.

However I would like to modify the below script, in order to get the minimum, maximum, and average time the request takes

The code correctly shows me the total execution time of the entire script, but I want to know the total,average, min and max execution time of the TRY block, also

I tried to put measure-command inside, but it prompts for an expression, so apparently 2 measure commands one nested after the other is not possible

```
 function Failure {
    $global:helpme = $body
    $global:helpmoref = $moref
    $global:result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $global:reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($global:result)
    $global:responseBody = $global:reader.ReadToEnd();
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "Status: A system exception was caught."
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red $global:responsebody
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor:Black -ForegroundColor:Red "The request body has been saved to `$global:helpme"
    break
}

 Measure-command {  
    If ((Get-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )  
    { Add-PSSnapIn -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell } 

    $StartDate=(GET-DATE)
    $CutOffDate=(Get-date).AddDays(-540)
    $SPAssignment = Start-SPAssignment
    $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb https://oursite/sites/billing -AssignmentCollection $spAssignment
    # Next step is to get the list:
    $SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["Bill Cycles"]
     $spqQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
            $spqQuery.Query =  
                "   <Where> 
                    <And>
                        <Eq> 
                            <FieldRef Name='Bill_x0020_Preparation_x0020_Status' /> 
                            <Value Type='Text'>COMPLETED</Value> 
                        </Eq> 
                        <Leq>
                            <FieldRef Name='Bill_x0020_to_x0020_date' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime'>
                                <Today OffsetDays='540' />
                            </Value>
                        </Leq>
                    </And>
                </Where>" 
    $spqQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Bill_x0020_Preparation_x0020_Status' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Bill_x0020_to_x0020_date' /><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" 
    $spqQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true 
    $splListItems = $SPList.GetItems($spqQuery) 
    $iNumber=1 
    $iNumberOfContentTypes=1 
    $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchived=0 
    $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchivedFailed=0 
    $cred = Get-Credential 
    foreach  ($splListItem in ($splListItems | Select-Object -First 10) )
    {
        $iNumber+=1 
        if( $splListItem["ContentType"] -eq "Bill Cycle"){           

           try {                
                    #Start-Sleep -s 65
                    $Url = "https://oursite/sites/billing/_vti_bin/DMS/DMSWebService.svc/Billing/ArchiveBillCycle/"+$splListItem["ID"]
                    #Write-Host $Url 
                    #https://oursite/sites/billing/_vti_bin/DMS/DMSWebService.svc/Billing/ArchiveBillCycle/145771
                    $r = Invoke-WebRequest -Credential $cred -Uri $Url   -TimeoutSec 180 -ErrorAction:Stop
                    #Write-Host $r.Content.ToString()
                    if($r.Content -like '*<RequestSucceeded>false</RequestSucceeded>*')
                    {
                        write-host "Archiving Failed, File # $iNumber - Bill Cycle Id:" $splListItem["ID"], "Title:" $splListItem["Title"] , "ContentType:" $splListItem["ContentType"] ,  "Status:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_Preparation_x0020_Status"] , "Billtodate:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_to_x0020_date"] -ForegroundColor Red 
                        $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchivedFailed+=1
                    }
                    elseif($r.Content -like '*<RequestSucceeded>true</RequestSucceeded>*')
                    {
                        write-host "Archived, File # $iNumber - Bill Cycle Id:" $splListItem["ID"], "Title:" $splListItem["Title"] , "ContentType:" $splListItem["ContentType"] ,  "Status:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_Preparation_x0020_Status"] , "Billtodate:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_to_x0020_date"] -ForegroundColor Green 
                        $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchived+=1
                    }
                    else{
                        write-host "Archived, File # $iNumber - Bill Cycle Id:" $splListItem["ID"], "Title:" $splListItem["Title"] , "ContentType:" $splListItem["ContentType"] ,  "Status:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_Preparation_x0020_Status"] , "Billtodate:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_to_x0020_date"] -ForegroundColor Green 
                        $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchived+=1
                    }   
           } 
           catch {
                $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchivedFailed+=1
                write-host "Archiving Failed, File # $iNumber - Bill Cycle Id:" $splListItem["ID"], "Title:" $splListItem["Title"] , "ContentType:" $splListItem["ContentType"] ,  "Status:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_Preparation_x0020_Status"] , "Billtodate:" $splListItem["Bill_x0020_to_x0020_date"] -ForegroundColor Red 
                Failure
           }

           $iNumberOfContentTypes+=1
        }              
    } 

    Write-Host "Number of items in the query: "  $iNumber
    Write-Host "Number of content types in the query: "  $iNumberOfContentTypes
    Write-Host "Number of bill cycles archived: "  $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchived
    Write-Host "Number of bill cycles archived failed: "  $iNumberOfBillCyclesArchivedFailed


}
```

Comment: Measure-Command returns just one timespan, to have `-Average`, `-Minimm` and `-Maximum` you'd need to feed `Measur-Object` with an array of those (and do some formatting).